# Strange issue with Struts 2 form handling

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm testing what will happen if I have a field set in my action which is an integer, and someone tried to provide a `String` value for it.

For example:

```
public class FooAction extends ActionSupport
{
   private Integer foo;
   public Integer getFoo() 
   { ... }

   public void setFoo(Integer foo)
   {... }

   public String execute()
   {
      System.out.println( foo );
      return SUCCESS;
   }
}
```

If I create the following form and try to submit it:

```
<form method="post" action="/foo.action">
  <input type="text" name="foo" />
  <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

Then, if I provide only a number within the textbox, it works fine.

However, if I provide a string such as 'bar' in the textbox, then the following happens:

1) In the output window in the IDE, I see a warning about an exception about trying to set a string value to an integer field.

2) Immediately after that, I see 'null' as the value of `foo`.

3) However, strangely, in the .jsp file which I have set to be displayed when the form is submitted, I have the following line:

```
<h2><s:property value="foo" /></h2>
```

The output from this line of the jsp is `bar` (which is what I typed in the form), even though the `foo` field is integer and I got `null` in the output window when trying to output it.

Can anyone explain what the deal is?

Comment: so basically you are returning SUCCESS even when not.  I guess that the request parameter is set correctly but conversion fails

Comment: @user2310289 Yes, just for debugging purposes. But what I don't understand is, in the .jsp file, how can it display the string value of foo when in the action, it shows null for it?

Comment: @user2310289 By the way, even if I return error, I still see the warning about the exception in console (so it still tries to assign string value to integer field), and if i use the same .jsp for the error result, it still outputs the string value of `foo`

Comment: And what you expect? You want to show entered value in JSP to the user if it fails, don't you?

Comment: @AleksandrM I don't expect anything.. I'm just curious about 1) How is it assigning a string value to an integer field, 2) Why does it show null in console, but shows the string in the .jsp?

Comment: I wonder if the parameter in the request is set as a String, but can not convert to int in the class, but in the JSP it is just a String

Comment: @user2310289 parameter is definitely string in the request.. but I thought that in the jsp, it would map to the integer field on the action rather than the string parameter in request?

Comment: @ClickUpvote Obviously it's not assigning a string to an integer field. And it's an `Integer`, which can be null, as it might be with a validation failure.

Comment: Just to be clear, each parameter in the request is a String.  Struts 2 has a set of default converters that manage basic conversions to your action attributes without you knowing it.  Check the following url: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html

Comment: By the way, who down-voted this question.  It is a legit question to ask since there is a lot of stuff happening behind the scenes in struts 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have the conversionError interceptor on your stack.

Here is an snippet from the [javadoc](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ConversionErrorInterceptor.html)

> In addition, any field that contains a validation error has its original value saved such that any subsequent requests for that value return the original value rather than the value in the action. This is important because if the value "abc" is submitted and can't be converted to an int, we want to display the original string ("abc") again rather than the int value (likely 0, which would make very little sense to the user).

Comment: This must be it. I have no interceptors set, so it must be calling that interceptor by default.

Comment: This interceptor is on the struts default stack so it might come from there.